# Pyspark - How to seperate specific a value from a row into its own column

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Using pysparks and working with some yelp data, I'm trying to do a count of those that are elite members and those that aren't.

```
df_Usr2.groupby(['name', 'business_id', 'Elite_Member']).count().sort('business_id', acending=True).show(50, truncate=False)
```

When I create a count right now it displays them top to bottom as shown below, what I was trying to do was to get them shown side by side, with a .withColumn that had a the count for None Elites.

Currently its like this:

```
[name]   [Business_id]   [EliteMem] [Count]
   a          123            No        5
   a          123            Yes      10
```

I was hoping for something more along the lines of this:

```
 [name]   [Business_id]   [EliteMem] [NonEliteMem]
    a          123            10           5
```

[Heres a look of what my dataframe looks like exactly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EmIjC.png)

Comment: Could you show us how the source data looks? The  `df_Usr2` DF data.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `groupby` with `pivot` and `sum` (http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.GroupedData.pivot)

```
df1 = sqlContext.createDataFrame([
                    Row(name="a",
                        business_id=123,
                        elitemem="no",
                        count=5),
                    Row(name="a",
                        business_id=123,
                        elitemem="yes",
                        count=10)]
                        )

 df1.show()
+-----------+-----+--------+----+
|business_id|count|elitemem|name|
+-----------+-----+--------+----+
|        123|    5|      no|   a|
|        123|   10|     yes|   a|
+-----------+-----+--------+----+

df1.groupby('name','business_id').pivot('elitemem',['no','yes']).sum('count').show()
+----+-----------+---+---+
|name|business_id| no|yes|
+----+-----------+---+---+
|   a|        123|  5| 10|
+----+-----------+---+---+
```

If you are worried about the column names being `no` and `yes`, you can follow this approach.

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
df2 = df1.withColumn("elitemem_new",F.when(df1['elitemem']=="yes","elitemem").otherwise("nonelitemem"))

 df2.groupby('name','business_id').pivot('elitemem_new').sum('count').show()
+----+-----------+--------+-----------+
|name|business_id|elitemem|nonelitemem|
+----+-----------+--------+-----------+
|   a|        123|      10|          5|
+----+-----------+--------+-----------+
```